# Why does my HTML table have two borders?

Tags: html, css

I've tried for a while on this one and can't seem to figure it out. Why does my HTML table have double borders around it? I just want one border that has rounded edges. Currently, I have one border that is rounded, and once border that is straight. I also need the border that divides the cells.

It seems strangely difficult to get this to work... Did I do something wrong here?

The CSS:

```
.bottom-table  {  
    border-collapse: separate !important;  
    border-radius: 10px !important;  
    width: 75%;  
    text-align: center;  
    margin-right: auto;  
    margin-left: auto;  
}  

#bottomTable{  
    padding-bottom: 50px;  
}  

.bottom-table td {  
    padding-left: 10px;  
    padding-right: 10px;  
    padding-top: 20px;  
    padding-bottom: 40px;  
    vertical-align: top;  
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5km7h/)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, your `table` has one and your `td` elements have the other border. Remove one:

```
.bottom-table td {
    border: 0;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/5km7h/3/

And to add a cell divider, you can add a right border to the left cell, for example:

```
.bottom-table td:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/5km7h/4/

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5km7h/2/)

Change `border-collapse:seperate` to `collapse`

It is because default borders are applied to the cells, by using `seperate` you are effectively saying for each cell to have seperated borders (defined by `border-spacing`)

[**More on `border-collapse` from MDN**](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mdn%20border-collapse)

> The border-collapse CSS property selects a table's border model. This
>   has a big influence on the look and style of the table cells.
>
> The separated model is the traditional HTML table border model.
>   Adjacent cells each have their own distinct borders. The distance
>   between them given by the border-spacing property.

### [With rounded edges](http://jsfiddle.net/5km7h/5/)

To maintain the rounded edges, you will need to employ a few tricks- namely apply the border to the parent `div` with the rounded edges, then add a border to the right hand side of the first cell, [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5km7h/5/), CSS:

```
#bottomTable {
    border:1px solid;/* <-- add border to parent div */
    border-radius:10px;/* <-- round corners */
}
.bottom-table {
    border-collapse:collapse;/* <-- collapse table borders */
    width: 75%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border:none;/* <-- remove default border*/
}
.bottom-table td:first-child {
    border-right:1px solid;/* <-- add border to first cell */
}
.bottom-table td {
    border:none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick comment on this, if you do this change you lose the rounded corners.

Comment: Yeah, exactly... I have tried this already, but I need the rounded corners. That's the whole point...

Answer (score 0):

The table has a single border but each table cell has a border of its own.

Use `border-collapse: collapse` instead of `separate` to merge touching cell and table borders or set `border: 0` for the table cells to remove the inner borders entirely.